# UDP Packet not being recieved on localhost

Tags: java, sockets, networking

Hey guys im having trouble recieving UDP packets in java. I've currently tested it on locolhost and my uni's servers. No exceptions are being thrown its just my client not recieve a single packet.  Heres some code :
 at line 136 in my Server calls

`ps.PacketUtilSendFileLength();`

```
// Packet Service class snippet
   public void PacketUtilSendFileLength() throws IOException {
        DatagramPacket packet = null;
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
        buffer.putLong(file_length);
        buffer.flip();



        if (V6_Mode) {
            packet = new DatagramPacket(hash(buffer.array()), buffer.array().length, Hostv6, PORT);

        } else packet = new DatagramPacket(hash(buffer.array()), buffer.array().length, Hostv4, PORT);


        datagramSocket.send(packet);

    }
```

My client which calls

````
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);// these 2 lines are made at the start of the main
        DatagramPacket FileLength_ACK = new DatagramPacket(buffer.array(),buffer.array().length);
    ...
    ps.PacketUtilRecieve(FileLength_ACK);```

```    public DatagramPacket PacketUtilRecieve(DatagramPacket p){

        try {
            datagramSocket.receive(p);
            return p;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            PacketUtilSendError();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
````

my Server is sending the packet in but my client never recieves it what am i doing wrong here?

full code : https://github.com/WeStandUnited/SlidingWindow/tree/master/src

Comment: Does the server receives the first packet from the client ? The client may be behind a router where ports will not be open until you begin sending first

Comment: The server and the client communicate fine before this they do a key exchange so the server and the client have each others addresses. I am sending over local host in my test. I've also tested on 2 different pairs of machines on 2 different networks.